Unity проекты не отображают canvas, но его видно
Unity проекты не отображают canvas, но его видно. Первый раз это произошло в создании режима EliteSquad (а точнее карты для нее) в проекте Chicken Gun. Зашел в другой проект (точнее создал его) и опять происходит это. Я переустанавливал Unity UI, чинил файлы, ничего не помогает.

Извините, я просто не поставил Gizmos.
